# How to get the real Windows Live contact email addresses with the API?

Tags: api, email, windows-live

I'm wondering how Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn (to name a few) are using the Windows Live API to find the email addresses of the friends of a user to send them invitations. 
When I try to use the Windows Live API I only get the email_hashes which can only be used to compare with existing user email of a system instead of sending them invitations.

Are these services paying Microsoft to benefit of an advanced API ?

Thank you,
Sébastien

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is add the following scope to the list of scopes you are requesting:

"wl.contacts_emails"

e.g.

```
WL.login({scope: ["wl.basic", "wl.contacts_emails"]})
```

Comment: Cool, how did you find this? It's not documented - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243646.aspx#extended.
Are there any other undocumented scopes. Specifically, I'd like the user profile image for contacts.